# In Visual Studio, is there a quick way to generate these types of comment blocks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, comments

*If anyone knows the name for these types of comments, if one exists, please modify my question.*

I frequently see comment blocks such as this:

```
/**********************************************
 *          Some Important Text Here
 **********************************************/
```

Sometimes they can look like this:

```
/**********************************************
  *********  Some Important Text Here  ******* 
 **********************************************/
```

I've also seen them prettier than that.

They seem useful for noting sections of code, and important messages, such as license blocks. But, I feel like there *must* be a "lazy" way of doing this in Visual Studio, or at least an addon, because typing them manually is a pain.

Thanks!

**P.S.** If this feature or a point-and-click way to do it doesn't exist, then I know what VS plugin I'm writing next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a code snippet for them

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps look at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), it is great for writing neat, clean, consistent style commenting in your code. It uses XML markup, and can later be exported for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fixed-text blocks, then add a Code Snippet for each one you need.

If you want auto-generated documentation blocks for absolutely any code element, then you might like to try my addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/). (Similar to GhostDoc, but with significantly more features, a much better documentation generation engine, better formatting control (e.g. word wrapping of comments and documentation comments) and support for many more programming languages and documentation block styles).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a toolbar macro which inserts that text at your cursor position when you click on the toolbar icon.